# FB js invite friend

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

This is not duplicate, as it may seam from the title. Continue reading.

So what I want is to create JS script, which would automatically send an invitation to a certain user to become a friend.

How do I approach this?

Basically, user will need to copy my JS code to browser URL bar, which will append JS directly to the Facebook session. (meaning that now I can send POST request on behalf of the user)

Of course, users are aware about the final result. (it is sort of blind-dating what I am thinking to make)

Is this theoretically possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I think the best way to implement something like this is to use Facebook Connect to authenticate users on your site and connect the users that way. Once the users have connected on your site, invite them to connect on Facebook too (by using the method below or just linking to their profile). This way, you're controlling the "meet", like you want, but you're also allowing them to connect on Facebook in a legitimate way.

---

Give [this dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/) a shot, and just direct the user to:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/friends/?id=<USER_ID_TO_BE_ADDED>&app_id&<APP_ID>&redirect_uri=<ADDRESS_IN_YOUR_DOMAIN>
```

Alternatively, you could simply open a popup with that URL using `window.open`.

From what you suggested in your question though, it doesn't sound like you wish to use the feature like Facebook intended. From the usage notes:

> This feature is intended to help users become friends on Facebook with people that they are connected to in real life. You should not use this feature to encourage users to friend other users that they are not connected to in real life. If your app is found to be encouraging this behavior, your usage of this feature may be disabled.

Comment: `app_id=<APP_ID>`? This is not `app-based`, this is standalone website. And what does app have to do with one person inviting other person to friends?

Comment: I copied that URL from the documentation. I'm pretty sure you're going to have an easier time doing this using the official Facebook method (an app, using the SDK) rather than a hack.

Comment: @Jimmy Sawczuk, I just read the documentation. You kinda missed the point of the question: this is supposed to be blind-dating. Therefore, unless the other person will agree to add him (the explanation will be given in the friend request) the person should not know whom the request was sent. (it will be sent to one of his friend friends)

Comment: you cannot do it for standalone sites.

Comment: This is what I read: "So what I want is to create JS script, which would automatically send an invitation to a certain user to become a friend." That may or may not be what you're looking for, but I believe my answer answers that question.

Comment: @ming yeow, yes I can if the user will append the JS code to this browser session. I did find one way, but it is overcomplicated and requires multiple request-response exchange. I wonder if anyone can suggest straightforward way to do it without trying to acquire form-ids, etc. and trying to simulate client behavior.

Comment: @Guy I added something to my answer, let me know if that helps.